# How to change title text as iframes' title text?

Tags: javascript

How to change window title text as iframe's title text ?

Lets say...

main.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title A</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

iframe.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title B</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the window title show as "title B"

So I tried,

```
window.parent.document.title = "Your new title";
```

put this code on iframe.html, not work for me

Please help.

Comment: `top.document.title = ...` should do the trick, as long as both of the documents are sharing the same domain. Though, your code should also work as it is.

Comment: `document.title = newTitle`

Comment: your statement, "put this code on iframe.html, not work for me" and your question, "I want the window title show as *title B* " are contradicting. Do you want the parent title to be same as iframe's title or iframe title to be same as parent title? where does your code live, in iframe or the parent document?

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary I'm not arguing, that the question isn't in need of improvement, but the only place where you actually can see the "window title" is the page's tab button on the tab bar (which by default is the title of the top window). Considering this, it's most likely, that OP wants to show the title of the iframe document in the tab bar.

Comment: Is main.html and iframe.html in different documents? Are they both loaded into one document so that you can access the values